# How good is ValueTuple for large objects?

Tags: c#

I going to return big `List` of objects as one of the parameters in my `ValueTuple`. Somethings like this:

```
(bool success, List<TemplateModel> data string error)> Get(string templateName);
```

As far as `ValueTuple` is a struct and `List` inside of struct I suppose have to store in heap. So there shouldn't be any kind of performance issue. Is this make sense? Does this approach have any pitfalls?

Comment: Firstly, do you really need the performance (if any) of using a tuple (see [this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/))? Is the benefit you get worth the reduced readability of using a standard class to hold these details?

Comment: @DavidG on the project for which I came, Tuple is the most often return type

Comment: Honestly speaking, you should learn how to profile your application, rather than take assumption that return value have considerable impact on performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `List<string>` and `string` are reference types so will be stored on the heap. The tuple itself will only contain a reference to these data items.

The size of the reference itself doesn't depend on the number of items in the list or characters in the string. It's usually 32 bits or maybe 64 bits at most.

Most of the time micro-optimisations of this nature won't have any noticeable impact on performance.